# Reading file directory using scanner is not working

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I want to read a file and its directory using scanner. The problem is the directory is not read through scanner because there is a white space in it. I tried to handle it with `S.nextLine()` but it doesn't skip execution and skip to the rest of the code. 
This is the code:

```
public class readFile {

   public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.print("Enter test file directory: ");
    testFile = S.nextLine();
    //testFile = "C:\\Users\\firstname lastname\\Desktop\\test1.txt"; This works 
    File test = new File(testFile);
    try
    {
      Scanner readFile = new Scanner(test);

      while(readFile.hasNextLine())
     {
        int i = readFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
     }
     readFile.close();
     }catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("File doesn't exist");}
   }
}
```

Comment: What does it print if you write `System.out.println(testFile);`?

Comment: C:\\Users\\firstname

Comment: Are you sure the file exists cause this code works fine for me...make sure you declare `String testFile;` I don't see it declared anywhere also `Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);`.

Comment: Ah I see a cause of a problem: You've edited your username to `firstname lastname` for the constant version. `Scanner#next()` reads everything until the next whitespace. Therefore it doesn't read the whole line if you have a whitespace in your path. Use `nextLine()` instead.

Comment: I realized that the problem is i have a space in my username. so I need to know how to handle the space in the directory? Thank you

Comment: @Tom Yeah i knew its the white space, but `nextLine` doesn't work. it doesn't wait for my typing and skip to the rest of the code emmediately

Comment: Can you update your code, please?

Comment: If this code is used in a project with more input requests to the user, then keep in mind, that you can't directly call `nextLine()` if you used `nextInt()` or `nextDouble` or something like that before that call.

Comment: @Tom I see. So what to do? should i create another scanner for `nextLine()` ?

Comment: No not necessary, [read this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint) for a solution.